# using threads with spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

i'm using spring boot, i have some class services and controleurs, now i want to create a thread that verify if a folder contain files or not? i create the class for verifing the existance of files but now i want to integrate this class with spring boot. this is my code :

```
public class Linstenerfile implements Runnable{
String fichier ="C:/Project/containerFiles/snapshot.txt";
ControlleurFile l =new ControlleurFile();
File file = new File(fichier);
@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    while(true)
    { 
        if(file.exists())
        {
             try {
                File Subscriberoffref=l.CreateSubscripberFile(file,"data");
                List<AbonneOffreDTO1> suscriberOffredata=l.GetCvsData(Subscriberoffref);
                l.VerifyData(suscriberOffredata);
                //  file.delete();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        else
        {
        System.out.println("thread running");
        }
    }
}
```

}

and this the springboot class application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class GateWayProjectApplication {


public static void main(String[] args)   {

    SpringApplication.run(GateWayProjectApplication.class, args);
    Linstenerfile k =new Linstenerfile();
    k.run();
}
```

and this is the code verifydata method

```
public void VerifyData(List<AbonneOffreDTO1> lisaboff)
    {   
        System.out.println(abonneservice.GetAbonnesize());
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: the problem is when i run this application, always i get java.lang.NullPointerException in this ligne  System.out.println(abonneservice.GetAbonnesize());

Comment: Actually calling run() on Runnable won't create new Thread; You should do something like:
`
Thread thread = new Thread(new ListenerFile());
thread.start;
`
And it'll be better to put some sleep() instructions inside while() check.